# New unit testing framework for Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, frameworks

I'm looking into new frameworks to perform some unit testing on a java project. I am aware of junit, but beyond that I haven't found much of consequence. Are there any frameworks out there that are recommended?

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't a specific programming problem.  Google with -junit and some options should turn up.

Comment: Sorry @bill, I didn't realize this was out of line. From the FAQ:              "Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers …

a specific programming problem
a software algorithm
software tools commonly used by programmers
matters that are unique to the programming profession
" I saw this to be a "software tool commonly used by programmers", how do you figure differently?

Comment: What is the software tool you're asking about?  You don't have one, you're just asking for recommendations.  If you keep reading on that page you'll see what kinds of questions not to ask, such as `every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”`

Answer (score 3):

TestNG is something you have a look at. I have used it. Provides a lot of features that JUnit provides.

This page has [advantages of TestNG Over Junit](http://testng.org/doc/index.html).

Comment: I've read the TestNG book.  Spends most of their time saying they are better than junit instead of just excelling :(

Comment: I've read the TestNG book and used TestNG. I found it to both claim and demonstrate excellence.

Comment: I have used both JUnit and TestNG. But nothing compels me not to use JUnit.

Answer (score 1):

[TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html) is quite a popular choice. And then there is [JDave](http://jdave.org/) if you are looking for a BDD style framework.

Answer (score 1):

To complement JUnit, there are mocking libraries such as JMock and EasyMock.

Answer (score 0):

If it's pure unit testing, maybe try TestNG, but either way you should be fine with either JUnit or TestNG